# Sending parameter to Ransack from Active Admin filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, filter, activeadmin, arel

I'm trying to make a filter in Active Admin on a customer's first name and last name in one single input field. The first_name and last_name are separate fields.

My solution fails if you have a middle name. If the customer's name is "John H. Smith", then "John" and "Smith" give the correct result, but "John Smith" will not find anything because of the extra 'H.'.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Customer do
  ...
  filter :full_name_cont, label: 'Name', as: :string
end

# In the Customer model:

ransacker :full_name, formatter: proc { |full_name| full_name.downcase.to_s } do |parent|
     Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('||',
          Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('||',
             parent.table[:first_name], ' '
          ),
          parent.table[:last_name]
     )
end
```

So now I'm trying to send the search term "John H. Smith" as a parameter to ransacker, so I can split the name up into multiple parts and search if any of them match first name or last name:

```
ransacker :full_name, args: [:parent, :ransacker_args] do |parent, args|
   full_name = args.first
   search_items = full_name.split(" ")
   condition = "concat_ws(first_name, ' ', last_name) LIKE '%#{search_items.first}%'"
   search_items.each do |item|
      condition += " OR concat_ws(first_name, ' ', last_name) LIKE '%#{item}%'" if item != search_items.first
   end
   Arel.sql(condition)
end
```

Unfortunately, args is always empty.

Does anyone know how to send parameters to ransacker?

Comment: Just to confirm - have you tried what is mentioned in item 6 here https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/using-ransackers ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm aiming for. But I'm not sure how to insert something similar in the filter: 
`Person.ransack(
  c: [{
    a: {
      '0' => {
        name: 'author_max_title_of_article_where_body_length_between',
        ransacker_args: [10, 100]
      }
    },
    p: 'cont',
    v: ['Ransackers can take arguments']
  }]
)`

Comment: @ElenaTanasoiu please check https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/issues/164#issuecomment-223040569

Comment: have your found a solution here ?

Comment: Yes, I've added the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this was to create a new Ransack predicate that considers spaces as wildcards.

The idea was also presented in this issue: [Make an OR with ransack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940629/make-an-or-with-ransack)

```
# In config/initializers/ransack.rb

Ransack.configure do |config|
  config.add_predicate 'contains',
         :arel_predicate => 'matches', # so we can use the SQL wildcard "%"
         # Format the incoming value: add the SQL wildcard character "%" to the beginning and the end of
         # the string, replace spaces by "%", and replace multiple occurrences of "%" by a single "%".
         # For using * and ? instead as wild cards use this #{Ransack::Constants.escape_wildcards(v).gsub("*", "%").gsub('?','_')}
         :formatter => proc {|v| ("%#{v.gsub(" ", "%")}%").squeeze("%")}
end
```

And then in the model I used this ransack code from the examples in https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/using-ransackers#5-search-on-a-concatenated-full-name-from-first_name-and-last_name-several-examples:

```
# ActiveAdmin - customers.rb
# I re-open the model 
class Customer
  ransacker :full_name do |parent|
       Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('||',
          Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('||',
              parent.table[:first_name], ' '),
                  parent.table[:last_name])
  end
end

ActiveAdmin.register Customer do
...
end
```